# How to separate the unique values from a multiple related columns in kusto and summarize based on them?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a table with data like this: -

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Audience | A_Types | B_Types | C_Types | D_Types | IsTall | IsRed | IsHeavy |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Noah    | 3,4,5   | 1,2,5   |  1,5,6  | 1,2,3   |   0    |   1   |    1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Rebecca | 3,4,4,6 | 1,2,3,4 | 2,3,4,5 | 2,3,4,5 |   1    |   0   |    0    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Noah    | 3,4     | 1,2     |  1,5    | 1,2     |   0    |   1   |    1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Extra info:

1. Audience can take only 5 distinct values and can't be empty.
2. A_Types, B_Types, C_Types, D_Types is a comma separated string of positive integers, they can be empty, but they will always have the same length for any given row.
   i.e. either they all will be empty for a given row or will have the same length of comma separated values for a given row.

The below rows are not allowed to exist.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Audience | A_Types | B_Types | C_Types | D_Types | IsTall | IsRed | IsHeavy |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Noah    | 3,4,5   | 1,2     |         | 1,2,3   |   0    |   1   |    1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Rebecca | 3,4    | 1,2,3,4  |         | 2,3     |   0    |   1   |    1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

3. IsTall and IsRed can be empty for any given row, but either both will be empty or both will have some value.
4. IsHeavy can be empty.

I want to get the count of everything summarized on the "Is*" columns' values, Audience and the indiviual values of the "*_Types" columns

I wrote the following query: -

```
TableName
| where Audience in ("Noah", "Rebecca", "Puyol", "Enkir", "Doman")
| extend A_Types = split(A_Types, ",")
| extend B_Types = split(B_Types, ",")
| extend C_Types = split(C_Types, ",")
| extend D_Types = split(D_Types, ",")
| mv-expand A_Type = A_Types to typeof(string)
| mv-expand B_Type = B_Types to typeof(string)
| mv-expand C_Type = C_Types to typeof(string)
| mv-expand D_Type = D_Types to typeof(string)
| summarize count() by
            A_Type,
            B_Type,
            C_Type,
            D_Type,
            IsRed,
            IsTall,
            IsHeavy,
            Audience
```

I am seeing some inconsistency with the above query results, can someone suggest a better query or can comment if this query is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the mv-expand for the relevant columns in one operation so that you get the matching values in each array in the same row. for example:

```
let Data = datatable(Audience:string,  A_Types:dynamic, B_Types:dynamic, C_Types:dynamic, D_Types:dynamic, IsTall:int, IsRed:int, IsHeavy:int)
["Noah", dynamic([3,4,5]),  dynamic([1,2,5]),    dynamic([1,5,6]),  dynamic([ 1,2,3]), 0 ,1 , 1,
 "Rebecca", dynamic([3,4,4,6]), dynamic([1,2,3,4]), dynamic([2,3,4,5]), dynamic([2,3,4,5]), 1 ,  0 ,0,
 "Noah", dynamic([3,4]),  dynamic([1,2]),    dynamic([1,5]),  dynamic([ 1,2]), 0 ,1 , 1];
Data
| mv-expand A_Types to typeof(int), B_Types to typeof(int), C_Types to typeof(int), D_Types to typeof(int)
| summarize sum(IsTall), sum(IsHeavy), sum(IsRed) by Audience, A_Types, B_Types, C_Types, D_Types
```

Results:

[image]